# Steps to simplify a Boolean Expression

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Simplify: $(x \land y) \lor (x \land \neg y) \lor (\neg x \land y)$

I need to simplify this using the using properties going step by step. I keep ending up with $(x \land y)$ as the answer but when I map is out I get that is should be $(x \lor y)$. Any help would be appreciated I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, an easy way is to actually compute the value since there are only 4 possibilities. This yields $x \lor y$.

Comment: This may duplicate what copper.hat said, but you can always make a truth table, and then find the simplest expression that gives you the final column in the table.

Answer (score 2):

First, we'll simplify the first two terms to $x$, then we'll simplify the entire statment $x \lor (\lnot x \land y)$:

$$(x \land y) \lor (x \land \lnot y) \equiv x \land (y \lor \lnot y) = x$$

$$x \lor (\lnot x \land y)\equiv (x \lor \lnot x) \land (x \lor y) \equiv x \lor y$$

Answer (score 1):

$(x \land y) \lor (x \land \lnot y) = x$, so $(x \land y) \lor (x \land \lnot y) \lor (\lnot x \land y) = x \lor (\lnot x \land y)$

$x = x \lor (x \land y)$, so $x \lor (\lnot x \land y) = x \lor (x \land y) \lor (\lnot x \land y) $

$( x \land y ) \lor (\lnot x \land y) = y$, so $x \lor ( x \land y ) \lor (\lnot x \land  y)  = x \lor y$

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much! I see that I was not distributing correctly when I started and it got all messed up!

Comment: @scottboughton You may accept this answer if you think it sufficiently answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

$(x \land y) \lor (x \land \neg y) \lor (\neg x \land y) \Leftrightarrow$ (Adjacency)

$x \lor (\neg x \land y) \Leftrightarrow$ (Reduction)

$x \lor y$